# Unwind segue doesn't dismiss intermediate ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a simple app with two ViewControllers. View controller A presents B programmatically (by instantiating it and calling present). Then B, depending on user input, may perform an unwindSegue to A (which works fine) or present another instance of B (again programmatically via present). This can be repeated in a arbitrarily long walk of B view controllers.

The problem is that whenever more than one B instance was shown, the unwind segue works, A comes in with the custom animation I set up for it but then the previous B appears.

- A -> B -> (unwind) -> A -- Works fine
- A -> B_1 -> B_2 -> ... -> B_N -> (unwind) -> A appears but then B_(N-1) shows.

I tried dismissing B_i when I present B_(i+1), but then all B's are dismissed and I end up in A.

I hope my explanation isn't too convoluted!

I don't know if it makes any difference, but B is a TableViewController and A is a regular ViewController.

Comment: Can you call ‘dismiss‘ in the unwind function and let me know what happens?

Comment: When I do that the source view is immediately dismissed (no animation) and the previous view is shown (B_i).